# Mac is typing wrong things with external keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I am using Macbook Pro mid 2015 with macOS Big Sur. When I try and use an external keyboard with it, it types wrong things! Like when I try to type + it shows ~ and when I try to type { it shows @ and a few more like that. All the letters are working fine. Its just the symbols. I have connected the Lenovo 500 wireless keyboard through a USB adapter. I have also remapped the shortcut keys.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the input source you are using?  US?  Tell us what you have at system preferences > keyboard > input sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, the Input Source in System Preferences was set to ABC. I saw the keyboard outline and realized it was different from my external keyboard. I changed it to a suitable one and it worked.

I found this thanks to Tom Gewecke’s comment.